# Error launching Blackberry Simulator

Tags: eclipse, jvm, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Since a Java update I have started to receive the following message when attempting to run the BlackBerry simulator.  Does anyone know how to resolve this?

> Packaging project xxxx 
>   C:\Program Files\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.36\components\bin\rapc.exe paramters 
>   I/O Error: Cannot run program "C:\Program": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified 
>   Packaging project xxx failed (took 0.797 seconds)

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same ever since I upgraded the Java on my system.

I was able to it by moving my eclipse installation from "C:/Program Files/eclipse" to D:/eclipse